# String translation through Google Translate stopped working

Tags: c#, google-translate, system.net

Some time ago I used a simple method to translate a dictionary from one language to another using Google Translate (without the cloud translation API). It looked similar to this:

```
private static Dictionary<string, string> StringTranslator(Dictionary<string, string> input)
{
    var output = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    var LanguagePair = "en|fr"; //let's take English to French as an example

    using (var web = new WebClient())
    {
        foreach (var pair in input)
        {
            var url = string.Format(@"http://www.google.com/translate_t?hl=en&ie=UTF8&text={0}&langpair={1}", pair.Value, LanguagePair);

            var w = web.DownloadString(url);

            w = w.Substring(w.IndexOf(@"<span title="">") + @"<span title="">".Length);
            w = w.Substring(w.IndexOf(">") + 1);
            w = w.Substring(0, w.IndexOf("</span>"));

            output.Add(pair.Key, w.Trim());
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

In this example, the dictionary's key will be the string name (irrelevant here) and value is the text to be translated.
The code worked fine until very recently, when Google changed the layout of Translator (I think). Now the output is always the full downloaded webpage, instead of just the translated text. Debugging shows that the

```
<span title="">
```

is nowhere to be found in the downloaded page, and neither is the translated text. Is there a way to fix it, or maybe another way to kind of implement an autotranslate like this one? Cheers.

EDIT: providing some more context
using the method in question:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var strings = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            {"str1", "one" },
            {"str2", "two" },
            { "strTest", "This is just nothing but a test message that will soon be translated into another language." }
        };

    var test = StringTranslator(strings);
}
```

All output strings in the dictionary look similar to this: https://pastebin.com/h4ahMRCb (pretty long and poorly formatted, but that's what it looks like when I get it)

Comment: What is the downloaded content? If it has your translation in it, there you go - just adjust your pattern matching. If it doesn't, what does it have? What is the response body?

Comment: @cwharris the problem is, the downloaded string does not have the translation in it. It's pretty much just some javascript code, judging by the fact that it's inside  <script> tags, but the translation is nowhere to be found.

Comment: We can help you if you provide more information. Please edit your post to include an example response.

Comment: @cwharris edited the post now

Comment: The page responds with a JavaScript application which sends an XHR to recieve the translation response. The app then presents that data to the user. Google is intentionally locking this service down. Bypassing security violates the terms of service. I strongly recommend taking a look at the official API.